# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered and Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, mysqli

This error occurs when someone submits user registeration form

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /public_html/register.php on line 55

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /public_html/register.php on line 55

this is the code around line 55

```
/* If there are no errors continue the registering process */
if(empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
    /* Define some needed variables */ 
    $password   = User::encrypt_password($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $active     = ($settings->email_confirmation == 0) ? "1" : "0";
    $email_code = md5($_POST['email'] + microtime());
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    /* Add the user to the database */
    $stmt = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `email_activation_code`, `name`, `active`, `ip`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email'], $email_code, $_POST['name'], $active, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    /* If active = 1 then login the user, else send the user an activation email */
    if($active == "1") {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = User::login($_POST['username'], $password);
        redirect("status/loggedin");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['success'][] = $language->register->success_message->registration;
        sendmail($_POST['email'], $settings->contact_email, $language->register->email->title, sprintf($language->register->email->content, $settings->url, $_POST['email'], $email_code));
        //printf($language->register->email->content, $settings->url, $_POST['email'], $email_code);
    }
}
```

Edit

tried with

```
$email_code = md5($_POST['email'] . microtime());
```

and using dot to concatenate fixed my issue as i found in comments.

Comment: You need to use a dot to concatenate, not a plus sign.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner tried it stil same warning and notice

Comment: you're going to need to show us more code.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner done

Comment: which line is line 55

Comment: @rpm192 $email_code = md5($_POST['email'] . microtime());

Comment: @Dilshad Are you sure that you saved/uploaded after making that change? What you have now would not produce that error.

Comment: The error means that PHP expects something to be a number, but it's not a number. Probably it's about the parameter of one of the functions.

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry my bad, using dot to concatenate fixed my issue, i was checking without saving.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo